# Paypal form submission - mobile

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, paypal

I`m using below code to submit values in to Paypal and it`s working.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <h2 style="font-family:Segoe UI;">Your Email :</h2>
    <input type="text" name="business" value="youremailaddress@yourdomain.com" style="width:1000px; height:50px; margin-left:30px;"/>
    <br />
    <h2 style="font-family:Segoe UI;">Driveway Size :</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="" />
    <select id="item_price" name="amount" style="width:1000px; height:50px; margin-left:30px;">
                            <option value="325">Single $325.00</option>
                            <option value="375">Double $375.00</option>
                            <option value="400">2.5 $400.00</option>
                            <option value="425">Triple $425.00</option>
                            <option value="450">3.5 $450.00</option>
                            <option value="475">Quad $475.00</option>
                        </select>
                        <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Buy!" style="margin-top:30px"/>

</form>
```

But this is desktop version. is there anyway that I can do same thing for mobiles?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You could for example use System.Net.WebClient to make the post towards the URL you have in the action field of the form.

Or, you can have the above HTML code embedded inside a web-browser control in your application.

Comment: Im having problem with the page which is navigated after I press buy button.. its having desktop layout and too big for the mobile. Is there anyway which I can navigate to a page which is compatible with mobiles?

Comment: Right this seems to be more a paypal related issue than a windows phone one. However, with regards to your problem you could find out if paypal has a mobile site or an Api for your needs.